# Powerup System unity rate of fire for raycast shooting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement a power-up where you collide with a box and then it ups your fire rate. Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Powerup : MonoBehaviour {

    public float multiplier = 3f;
    public float duration = 10f;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Pickup(other);
        }
    }
    IEnumerator Pickup(Collider player)
    {
        RaycastShooting.fireRate *= multiplier;
        Destroy(gameObject);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);

        RaycastShooting.fireRate = 4;


    }

}
```

Thanks in advance. It's probably a small problem that I didn't notice but it's a problem none the less.

Comment: you called "the coroutine" instead of starting it https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Answer (score 1):

You're not using Pickup() as a couroutine.
I think you should use the Invoke() method here as it is probably what you want:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Powerup : MonoBehaviour {

    public float multiplier = 3f;
    public float duration = 10f;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            RaycastShooting.fireRate *= multiplier;
            Destroy(other);
            Invoke("Reset", duration); // Calls method Reset after a period of time
        }
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        RaycastShooting.fireRate = 4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the coroutine instead of calling the Pickup function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Powerup : MonoBehaviour {

    public float multiplier = 3f;
    public float duration = 10f;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Pickup(other));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Pickup(Collider player)
    {
        RaycastShooting.fireRate *= multiplier;
        Destroy(player.gameObject);              
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        RaycastShooting.fireRate = 4;    
    }
}
```

Please notice that I changed `Destroy(gameObject);` into `Destroy(player.gameObject);`, as I think this is what you mean here.

I hope this will solve your problem !